# when combo box selection is null set dependent text box to null

Tags: combobox, textbox

I have a combo box *CboInst*on a form who's row source is a query that contains the fields:

[Instructor] and [Inhouse] from the Class_Catalog table.  On the 'Change' event of CboInst I have the following code:

```
Me.TxtHouse = Me.CboInst.Column(1)
```

The code populates a text box *TxtHouse* based on the choice from CboInst.

It works fine.  My problem is when I delete the contents of CboInst on the form, the text box continues to display the result of the previous choice until another choice is made.  For the purposes of this form, I need the text box to be blank when the combo box is blank.